# Vue/Vuex: mapState inside computed is not updating

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to make use of `mapState` and running into issues with reactive data.  I have the following inside my `Test.vue` component

```
 <template>
    <div> {{ name }} </div>
 </template>

computed: {
     ...mapState('user', ['age','name]
}
```

when my state `user.name` updates outside of the `Test.vue` component, the new value is not showing inside `Test.vue`.

so for example, if I have an update via a mutation in my `userStore`,

```
[SET_USER_NAME_MUTATION](state, value) {
      state.name = value;
},


commit('SET_USER_NAME_MUTATION', "John")
```

now in my Vuex store when I check chrome DevTools , `user { name: "John" }` , which is correct

Comment: Show how you're updating `user.name`. What version of Vue are you using?

Comment: just updated...I am updating the state via mutations in the `user` store.  Also, using Vue 2

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: I assume the missing `'` at the end of `...mapState('user', ['age','name]` is present in your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

You should mutate state through vuex actions instead of directly calling the mutation.
Try with something like this, assuming your state contains a `user` object with `name` property:

Vue component

```
<template>
    <div> 
        <span>{{ name }}</span> 
        <button @click="changeName">Change name</button>
    </div>
 </template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
    name: 'MyComponent',

    computed: {
        ...mapState({
            name: state => state.user.name
        })
    },

    methods: {
        changeName () {
            this.$store.dispatch('changeName', 'John Smith')
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Vuex store

```
// state
const state = {
    user: {
        name: null
    }
}

// getters
const getters = {
    // ...
}

// actions
const actions = {
    changeName ({ commit }, payload) {
        commit('setName', payload)
    }
}

// mutations
const mutations = {
    setName (state, payload) {
        state.user.name = payload
    }
}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

Anyway, it will be very helpful to know your state structure to a better approach as per your specific case